# How do I get my browser to display unicode correctly?

Tags: macos, browser, osx-leopard, unicode

I was trying to read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6163129/894284), but it looks like this:

[image: bad display]

How can I get my web browser to display this post correctly?

I'm using Chrome 17.0.963.78, Firefox 10.0.1, and Safari 4.0.5 on OS X 10.5.8.  All three fail in the same way on this post.  A solution for any one of them is fine.

---

Update:

after following @Jukka's instructions and installing the Symbola font, it looks like this (on Chrome):

[image: maybe fixed]

Is this correct?

Answer (score 4):

Download and install the [Symbola font](http://www.fonts2u.com/search.html?q=symbola). This is character rendering issue: the post contains, apparently for fun, rarely used characters which are not present in most fonts; they are partly iconic symbols, partly variants of letters coded as mathematical symbols in Unicode (e.g., mathematical bold fraktur letters). Symbola seems to be the only font available that contains all of them.

Comment: That definitely improves it.  I've add my current status to the OP; is that what it's supposed to look like?  There are still a few boxes appearing.

Comment: The remaining boxes should be icons like camels, and Firefox on Win 7 shows them that way but Chrome doesn’t but produces appearance like in your new screen shot. Apparently Chrome is not able to use fonts to the fullest extent without help. It possible misreads information in other fonts, expecting them to support these characters, and thus does not use Symbola for them. If I add the style sheet `h1 { font-family: Symbola !important }`, even Chrome gets it right,

Answer (score 1):

My Safari 5.1.3 on 10.7.3 displays all characters properly, and I haven't installed any additional fonts. The fraktur characters are included in STIXGeneral, and the emoji characters in Apple Color Emoji.

I guess you are still on 10.6 or 10.5? In any case, Lion should come with the STIX fonts and support emoji out of the box.

Chrome doesn't support Emoji at the moment though, see [lion - Why do emoji like  appear when I use Safari, but not Chrome? - Apple - Stack Exchange](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/41228/why-do-emoji-like-appear-when-i-use-safari-but-not-chrome).

Comment: 5.1.2 on 10.6 doesn't display them correctly as well.

Comment: Yes, I'm on 10.5.8.  Forgot to mention that.